# Sencha GXT4 : How to display text inside a pie chart?

Tags: java, gxt

I'm developing an application with the GWT framework and Sencha GXT on the front-end.
I managed to display some data in a pie chart but I would also like to have a label inside the donut pie chart like [image: this image]. I looked at the demo provided by sencha as well as the "Chart" class but I don't see any cases where there is text inside a pie chart. Is it feasible ?

I'm using "Sencha GXT 4.0.0 - Sencha for GWT"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution, I just need to use the setX method in my textConfig so my code looks something like this :

```
TextSprite textConfig = new TextSprite();
textConfig.setFont("Arial");
textConfig.setTextBaseline(TextBaseline.MIDDLE);
textConfig.setFontSize(18);
textConfig.setTextAnchor(TextAnchor.MIDDLE);
textConfig.setZIndex(15);
textConfig.setX(-150);
```

150 worked for me but maybe it won't for you.